# Get HREF value of clicked link loaded dynamically via Ajax in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This one has been driving me nuts. I have a div that has it's content loaded via Ajax when the page loads. The contents of the div are several hyperlinks. I am trying to get the HREF value of the clicked link using `$(this).attr('href')`. However, this always returns "undefined". I am guessing, since the hyperlinks were dynamically loaded via Ajax, jQuery is unable to return the HREF value. I have checked the page source and confirmed that all hyperlinks carry valid HREF links.

How can I retrieve the HREF values for hyperlinks dynamically loaded via Ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use jQuery on to bind the click function

```
$('#container a').on('click', function(event) {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
     return false;
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Not able to test this. Clicking the link now takes the browser to the linked page. I added `e.preventDefault();` to prevent this from happening. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either. The browser still follows the link.

Comment: make sure you dont have any javascript error. check using firefox console. use the "Perist"  mode and see whethere there is some errors in your script.

Comment: No errors at all. Tried the persist mode as well. Feel like banging my head on the table. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Finally got it working with .live
` jQuery('.portfolio-pagination a').live('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  alert(this.href);

 });`

Comment: @John: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Comment: Thx for the heads up. Any ideas on why would .live work and .on does not. .on normally acts as a replacement for .live

Comment: @John: on works for 1.7+  which version of jquery you are using ?

Comment: jQuery 1.7.1 is the version. The one that currently ships with Wordpress 3.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Is this code in an document ready block ?
What you have to keep in mind is that you have to use `.on("click")` on links that are added to the DOM after it has completely been loaded. Because when you are using`.click()` in you document ready block it cant work, because your a elements aren't even loaded at this point, because the ajax which loads the elements is executed slower and maybe executed after the DOM is ready.
So if you do it like

```
$('a').on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Everything should work for you.

Take a look at the documentation so maybe it makes it easier to understand:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thx for the reply. Not able to test this. Clicking the link now takes the browser to the linked page. I added `e.preventDefault();` to prevent this from happening. But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

John  the answers above works but the mistake you are making is to not following the logic behind it.

I hope the example I am making will make sense for you to finally understand how to call a function.

The first example says:

```
$('#container a').on('click', function(event) {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
     return false;
});
```

look at: `function(event)`
if you want to use `preventDefault();`

You should use `event.preventDefault();`

because you call the **event** function

you can either do the following:

1)

```
$('#container a').on('click', function() {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
     return false;
});
```

2)

```
$('#container a').on('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert($(this).attr('href'));

    });
```

3)

```
$('#container a').on('click', function(IamWhatYouWantMeToBe) {
         IamWhatYouWantMeToBe.preventDefault();
         alert($(this).attr('href'));

    });
```

4)

```
$('#container a').on('click', function() {
         preventDefault();
         alert($(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

5)

```
$('#container a').on('click', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             alert($(this).attr('href'));
        });
```

You should use `preventDefault();` before anything else inside your function,

or you can of course use instead only `return false;` at the end of your function as per the above examples.